# Button control template and DataTriggers

Tags: wpf, binding, controltemplate, datatrigger

In the application on which I'm working I have couple of items which I monitor. Every item has several states (on, off, change).
States are saved in model and DataContext of window is set to it.
Every button DataContext is set to single item in SortableBindingList.
In the XAML I have created Control Template for button and in DataTrigerrs in it.
However, sometimes item only shows for first button, sometimes only for first three buttons (depending on what content I put inside DataTrigger).
When I check in Snoop I see that all three buttons have correct DataContext set and there are no binding errors.
I expect that every button shows it's content  depending on value of 'serverstate' property however this does not happen.
What am I doing wrong?

Control Template goes to Window.Resources:

```
<ControlTemplate  x:Key="buttonTemplate" TargetType="Button" >
            <Border BorderThickness="1"
                    BorderBrush="Gray"
                    Margin="2"
                    Width="40" Height="35" 
                    >
                <Border.Background>
                    <SolidColorBrush Color="Brown" />
                </Border.Background>
                <ContentPresenter  />
            </Border>

            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding serverstate}"  Value="0">
                    <Setter Property="Content">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <TextBlock Name="a1"  Text="OFF" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Foreground="White" />
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding serverstate}" Value="1">
                    <Setter Property="Content">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <TextBlock Name="a2" Text="CHNG" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Foreground="White" />
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding serverstate}" Value="2">
                    <Setter Property="Content">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <TextBlock Name="a3" Text="ON" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Foreground="White" />
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </DataTrigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        </ControlTemplate>
```

Buttons:

```
<Button Name="state1" 
        DataContext="{Binding ActiveServers[0]}"
        Template="{StaticResource buttonTemplate}"
        />

<Button Name="state2" 
        DataContext="{Binding ActiveServers[1]}"
        Template="{StaticResource buttonTemplate}"
        />

<Button Name="state3" 
        DataContext="{Binding ActiveServers[2]}"
        Template="{StaticResource buttonTemplate}"
        />

<Button Name="state4" 
        DataContext="{Binding ActiveServers[3]}"
       Template="{StaticResource buttonTemplate}"
        />

<Button Name="state5" 
        DataContext="{Binding ActiveServers[4]}"
        Template="{StaticResource buttonTemplate}"
        />
```

This is how buttons shows up in window:

[image: How buttons in window show up]

Notice how button 4 and 5 completely ignore property value in datacontext.

Model:

```
public class Model : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public Model()
    {

    }

    private SortableBindingList<Server> _activeServers;
    public SortableBindingList<Server> ActiveServers
    {
        get {
            if (_activeServers == null)
            {
                _activeServers = new SortableBindingList<Server>();
            }

            return _activeServers; 
        }
        set
        {
            _activeServers = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("serverList");
        }
    }

    // Create the OnPropertyChanged method to raise the event 
    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I can suggest to use `ValueConverter` instead of `DataTrigger` for `Text` property in `TextBlocks`.

Comment: Ur first 3 buttons are showing correctly means that the `ActiveServers` collection contains some unknown `serverstate` value.

Comment: @AnjumSkhan No, everything is fine with my collection. Issue was however successfully resolved by user bars222 below!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is, that two buttons cann't use same `Content`. So each type of `Content` appears one time for each trigger value. You can avoid this by using `ContentTemplate`.
So the code should look like this (same for other `DataTriggers`). It allows you to change `DataTemplates` to more complicated later.

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding serverstate}" Value="2">
    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="ON" VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                           HorizontalAlignment="Center" Foreground="White" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>   
</DataTrigger>
```

Comment: Thanks, this has solved the problem!! :) However, I do not understand the difference between ContentTemplate and Content? Also I thought that I can use DataTemplate only for ItemsControls as they have multiple item instances. Can you point me to any resource where beginners like myself can understand this?

Comment: Wpf Unleashed is good book, also msdn and codeproject articles are good. C# and .net platform by andrew troelsen is good book for beginners. You can accept the answer to mark question as solved.

Comment: Yes WPF Unleashed is great book. Have accepted your answer as solved.

Answer (score 0):

Try  to change `Content` property, but not creating new `TextBlock`:

```
 <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding serverstate}"  Value="0">
                <Setter Property="Content" Value="OFF"></Setter>
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding serverstate}" Value="1">
                <Setter Property="Content" Value="CHNG"></Setter>
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding serverstate}" Value="2">
                <Setter Property="Content" Value="ON"></Setter>
            </DataTrigger>
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I can not use predefined instances of specific control. I need to use any, general type of Content inside this template. For example, it can be image, canvas or other layout (like gird or stackpanel).